# Update 1 particular month based upon what is passed into the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure in my SQL Server database:

```
USE [database_name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure_name]    
(
    @Month varchar(10)
)

AS

BEGIN       

SET NOCOUNT OFF  
UPDATE TableName SET
    January = IIF(@Month = 'January',0,'Leave it as it was')
    , February = NO CHANGE etc..
    WHERE 1=1

END
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm using of course. All I want to do is pass the procedure a month and then have that month and that month's only value in all of the rows update to 0 (it's a bit datatype) so that the rest of the month's are left as they are.

This table has a student id column and a year column in it to, so there are 14 columns. So that is where we get multiple rows from. So when I pass it January, I want the January column to be set to 0 for every student.

Comment: Sounds like your data model is the real problem here. If there can be one and only 1 month at a time why do you have a column for all of them. Wouldn't a column named ActiveMonth make a lot more sense? Then you have to look only at a single column regardless of the month to know what row is currently active. And if you are going to update the entire table what is the point of using "where 1 = 1"???

Comment: no, there's a student id column and then a column for each month in the year. Like I said before, this is simplified, I'm in the habit of using "where 1=1" because that makes it so that every line after that in the where clause has to have an "AND" in front of it. It works nicely when dynamically creating a query.

Comment: Right...Why do you need a column for every month when only 1 column can be set to 1? Sounds like you need two columns. StudentID, ActiveMonth (or whatever the 1 represents). Or can any number of the months be set to 1?

Comment: Something just seems a bit off here. Changing the value for every student is an indication that maybe something should be normalized here. Like maybe a single table to hold the month data?

Comment: the table in question indicates if billing has been submitted for a student for a given month for a given year. I agree that it probably could have been structured better but this is a preexisting system and would take a lot more work to fix it than to just go along with it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
January = CASE WHEN @Month = 'January' THEN 0 ELSE January END
```